# Cplex in C++: cannot open this source file

Tags: c++, c++11, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am learning concert technology, I am still at the beginning. I tried to open one of the examples (Ilolpex1.ccp) but when I run it the program says:

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h> : cannot open this source file
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your C++11 compiler is GCC (on Linux), i.e. `g++` command, you could run it as `g++ -H` to understand what headers are included, and you should add appropriate `-I` options to give relevant include directories.

Maybe you just need to add e.g. `-I /usr/local/include`

You might need to add the developer package of your libraries. (e.g. some `lib`*foo*`-dev` package on Debian or Ubuntu)

In practice, you'll better edit some variable in your `Makefile`, perhaps some `CXXFLAGS`

Answer (score 2):

The message you are seeing is during compilation, not running the program.  You need to add the concert *and* cplex include directories to your include path.  The examples are in the directory

```
<cplex_root_dir>/cplex/examples/src/cpp/
```

The include files are in

```
<cplex_root_dir>/cplex/include
<cplex_root_dir>/concert/include
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs maybe because you have installed a **32bit version** of IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio on a **64bit Windows**. So Visual Studio can't find related header files like "ilcplex".